# Getting raster legend to change to match raster in map when dynamic range setting is turned on using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, symbology, legend

When I bring a raster into ArcGIS Pro, I usually turn DRA on so the raster visualization changes depending on my map extent, but the legend never changes in the contents pane, or in the actual legend.

Is this a way so that the legend matches the map extent every time?